# Arduino does not return the desired output via serial port

Tags: struct, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I would like to send a list of elements inside a structure via serial port but the output produced by Arduino is abnormal.

A little help? What is the reason for this abnormal output?

```cpp
const int menu_max_item = 20;
int menu_num_item = 0;

typedef struct item_menu{
    String text; 
    void (*func)(void);
} t_item_menu;

t_item_menu arr_menu[menu_max_item];

void menu_add_item(String txt, void (*f)(void)){
  arr_menu[menu_num_item].text = txt;
  arr_menu[menu_num_item].func = f;
  menu_num_item++;
}

void fn_nd_function(){
  Serial.println('test');
}

void print_menu_lcd(){  
  for(int x = 0; x < 4 && x < menu_num_item; x++){
    lcd.setCursor(0,x);
    lcd.print(arr_menu[x].text);
  }
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) menu_add_item("item " + i, fn_nd_function);
}

void loop() {
  print_menu_lcd();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Real output

```
item 
tem 
em
```

Desired output

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

Comment: _sigh!_ Arduino is **not** C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of errors...

1. This code:

   ```cpp
   void fn_nd_function(){
     Serial.println('test');
   }
   ```

*test* is NOT a single character is it?  So why do you have it in single quotes?

But more importantly this which is the cause of your bad output:

```cpp
menu_add_item("item " + i, fn_nd_function);
```

`"item" + i` is NOT how you concatenate a number to the end of the character string `"item"`.  This is C++ not Java or Python.  You'll have to build that string separately.  Please don't be tempted to use the `String` class as that can cause other issues.

What is happening now is that you are passing `"item"` which is a pointer to the character array stored somewhere in memory holding the characters `'i'`, `'t'`, `'e'` and `'m'`.  When you add 1 to that pointer you end up with a pointer pointing to the `'t'` and when you add 2 you end up with a pointer pointing to the `'e'`.  So when you print from those pointers you only get the part after what that pointer points to.

You need to have a line ahead of that to build the string first.  Something along the lines of:

```cpp
char str[7] = "item  ";  // Note the two spaces to leave room for the digit
str[5] = i + '0';  // Add '0' to convert single digit to ascii
menu_add_item(str, fn_nd_function);
```